# Php finding word before a positive/negative word

Tags: php, words

i have a db with 3 tables review, pos and neg words for a film review im trying to detect if the word 'not' appears before a positive or negative word then add 1 to the pos count if it appears before a neg word ie this was not bad, and add 1 to the neg count if it appears before a pos word i.e this was not good

currently i have this method but it only seems to detect the not before a word once, how can i get it to detect through the whole text

```
$find = $review_text;
if (preg_match("/(?<=not) $negwords/i", $find)) 
{
echo $good++;
}
if (preg_match("/(?<=not) $poswords/i", $find)) 
{
echo $bad++;
}
```

Comment: Dont understand well. Do you running this code in loop ?

Comment: Please show the contents of `$negwords` and `$poswords`

Comment: i have a database that contains a table of positive and negative words

Comment: so like this 
    $pos = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM positive");
    $neg = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM negative");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
$negwords = array("bad","aweful");
```

If you want to check if there is any negative word preceded by not, you need to use alternatives in your query:

```
$words  = '(' + implode('|', $negwords) + ')'; // $words now contains (bad|aweful)
if(preg_match("/(?<=not) $words/i",$find)) {
     echo "match found!";
}
```

Note that $negwords *must not* contain any regexp special chars! ( like . * ? etc) - use `preg_quote` if needed.

To find out how many matches there were, you can use `preg_match_all` which returns the number of matches.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: will this method get a count for all the words that contain not in front of it ?

Comment: as said above words are stored on a DB

Answer (score 0):

The Guy Of Doom shows a clever solution for checking the entire text with a single regex, rather than having to loop over your word list and do one search per word. However, the problem you asked about is that regexp in PHP defaults to finding only the first match. As he mentioned, for that you need `preg_match_all()`. Just do this:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=not) $poswords/i", $find, $results);
```

`$results` does not need to be defined beforehand. After you call the function, PHP will put the results of the regexp into the variable `$results` as an array of arrays. The first array will contain what you want: the full string that was matched every time it found a match (the other arrays contain the parts of the string corresponding to your captured groups, i.e., parts of the expression in parentheses).

In some languages, you can use the g operator to get all matches (in the same place you put the case-insensitivity operator i), but in PHP this is the way you do it.

Comment: but i want a count of how many times it appears not just once which is the same as what i already had e.g if you have not good not bad not great the pos count should be 1 and neg count should be 2

Comment: Yes, the array `$results[0]` will have one element for every match it found. Conveniently, the function also returns that as a number. So, if there are three results and you do `$resultcount = preg_match_all("/(?<=not) $poswords/i", $find, $results);` then `$resultcount` will be equal to 3, and `$results[0]` will contain those three words.

Comment: Note that you'd have to do two searches for "good" and add the results together: one for good words without "not" in front of them, and one for bad words that do have "not" in front of them.

Comment: yes I already have a search for words without the not in front its just trying to do it with the not in front

Comment: the method just doesnt seem to work i have this
    $resultcount = preg_match_all("/(?<=not) $poswords/i", $find,      $results);
    if ($resultcount)
    {
     $bad++;
    }

Comment: i think the problem is to do with the space in front of 'not' so how can i check for a space in front of the not

Comment: the problem is its not picking up the pos or neg words only the number of 'not then word'

Comment: To find " not" with a space in front of it, just put a space in front of it in the regular expression: `"/(?<= not) $poswords/"`

Comment: When I run this code, `$results` contains an array with the words it found (actually, two copies of the array, but that's not important). Try `print_r($results[0])` and let me know what it shows.

Comment: i get this 
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )

Comment: and this was for:
 not good not bad not poor not boring not cheesy not great
using (?<= not) $negwords/i

Comment: I'm not sure what would produce this. Perhaps try `print_r($results)` instead of just results[0] and see if that sheds any light. You could also try inserting just one negative word in place of `negwords` and make sure that part isn't gumming it up.

Comment: prints this when i change negwords to good
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => good [1] => good [2] => good ) )
so the problem is recognising the words that are in the database

Comment: Did you build your $poswords with the code from the other response? It should end up looking something like `(good|great|nice|awesome)`.

Comment: Yes, you need to retrieve the words from the database into PHP, which will probably be in the form of an array. Then you build the $poswords part of the regular expression from that. Or you could do like you originally wanted, and loop over the query results searching for one word at a time. Either way, it sounds like that's the part of your code that's acting up right now.

Comment: how would i retrieve the words in to the database ?

Comment: It would just be a normal database query. If you don't know how to do that, you probably need to stop and learn a bit of SQL before you can proceed (or just hard-code the words into your script).

Comment: do you mean this 
$pos = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM positive");
$neg = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM negative");

Comment: That's an appropriate query, but you need to run it separately and then use one of the mysql fetch commands to retrieve the data. I suggest looking at a basic PHP/MySQL tutorial like [this one](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-mysql-tutorial.html?page=3).

Comment: Sorry, not without knowing your table structure. You'll need to learn at least a little bit about how SQL works regardless.

Comment: which tables ? the positive and negative have id and word as the fields